# What one point can see many targets

Tags: viewshed, line-of-sight

Let's say my phone company only has budget to build one cell tower,
but needs to serve points A, B, and C. How can I pick a location for
the new tower whose viewshed includes all three points?

Comment: You can't build a tower everywhere, and if you build it high enough, you'll always have visibility, so usually this would be done from the other side of the equation -- What lots are available, and what is the maximum permitted height. Otherwise you'd have to just lay down a tessellation of the area of service and try every centroid at several heights to identify candidates. In the end, you can't force people to sell you access, so you'll need a number of candidates for more advanced engineering analysis.

Comment: It will just be a standard 5 meter high lattice topped by a phony "half ton water tank". And we first plan to identify the candidate areas and then ask the farmers there. No point in asking where we later don't want to build anyway.

Oh and sorry @Vince about that question mark. I thought I forgot it.

Comment: Create a buffer for the points A B C with a distance equivalent to the range of the cell. Take the polygons representing the buffer then generate the centroid.

Answer (score -2):

Make viewsheds from points A, B, and C. Whatever pixels are marked as visible in all three viewsheds are possible candidate sites for your new tower.

Comment: Maybe just pick the highest point accessible in the region?

Comment: Viewsheds don't really work like this. You need to go the other direction -- From Z meters above this location, what can I see 1 meter above a coarse approximation of the surface? Once you have candidates that can "see" all three targets, you can use a finer DTM and include obstructions, then tweak the location and alter heights to gauge flexibility. It's got to be an iterative model, and you need to rank candidates.

Comment: @LeighBettenay yes, all targets see e.g., Mount McKinley, but there might not be roads, fiber, electricity, nearby. And it might be in a nature preserve, no permits available. Also a there might be fewer frequencies usable if we have to worry about interfering with the other valley behind it.

Comment: I thought this solution might be called the "reverse viewshed" but it turns out that term already has other uses. So currently there is no "official term" for this method...

Comment: @Vince but that would involve making thousands of viewsheds instead of just three, no? Also we are already using the smallest pixel size allowed by the government.

Comment: Your "reverse viewshed" algorithm doesn't exist. To make one, you'd have to do (tens? hundreds? thousands? of) thousands of viewsheds, not just three. This is why I was recommending you partition the space, and do coarse modelling first, to reduce the number of viewsheds. Without details on the extent of the model and the resolutions involved, this is just a discussion topic, more appropriate to [Chat] (which probably isn't visited enough to be of use).

Comment: It seems to me you are adding complications that were not in your original question. Many of these follow-ups could be answered by spatial analysis once you identified the top candidates. So perhaps choose not one but a series of the highest points then apply your filters sequentially until one stands out. I can't see how this could be automated.

Comment: OK, we completed the survey yesterday. And yes, it turns out, "Can we find any farmer out in the fields today whose uncle (the land owner) can be convinced to accept a cell tower on their land for no compensation, else we're just driving back to the office before it rains." is the overriding factor. But yes, that theoretical stuff was interesting.